# Ajax issues, data not being sent or even used

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to the AJAX scene sort to say, but i have used it before on another 'project' of mine, and it sends correctly and what not, but its a little dirty (and OCD), so i re-wrote it i also added some alerts to basically tell the info while i'm testing it (will be removed) but it gets to the ajax part and doesn't do anything.

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#continue').click(function(b) {

      //b.preventDefault();
      var username = $('#uid').val();
      var password = $('#pass').val();

      window.alert("BUTTON CLICKED");;
      window.alert("Username:"+username);
      window.alert("Password:"+password);

      if($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0)
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "login.php",
          data : { username : username, password : password },
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() { $('#status').content('<img src="Application/spinners/loading-cylon-red.svg" width="300" height="32" class="icon-loading"></img>'); },
          success: function(data) {
            if(data)
            {
              window.alert("LOGGED");

            } else {
              window.alert("FAILED");
            }
          }
        });
      }

    });
  });   
</script>
```

PHP: http://pastebin.com/hhvVSq1s

Comment: You'll have to include more info.  Where is the relevant HTML markup and what do you see in your JavaScript console?

Comment: What does the console think about it?

Comment: Yep, check the console. Find the post request in the network tab, and inspect the data that was sent, the url it was sent to, the mime type, etc.

Comment: There is no jQuery function `.content()` -> `beforeSend: function() { $('#status').content('...') }`. Try using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) -> `beforeSend: function() { $('#status').html('...'); }`

Comment: There isn't any errors in the console actually.
@Sean - thanks.

Comment: Issue fixed, it was actually related to .content, woops. Is anyone able to help me with the Loading icon, making it say a little longer for more of an effect?

Comment: How long to you want it to last? Is `$('#status')` replaced on success? What prevents it from 'staying a little longer'?

Comment: @Sean - $('#status') is cleared on success now, but it takes a few milliseconds and then its gone, this is why i'd like it to last a little longer. And for How long, i don't really know, not too long but long enough for the user to see it maybe 2 seconds as much as 3 (But what would you suggest?)

Comment: Instead of putting the `img` in `#status` I would dynamically add a `div` to the body, and remove it using `settimeout()`, ie. change `$('#status').content('<img...` to `$('body').append('<div id="loading" style="position:relative;z-index:10;"><img src="Application/spinners/loading-cylon-red.svg" width="300" height="32" class="icon-loading"></img></div>'); setTimeout(function(){$('#loading').remove();}, 3000);`